# Linear transformation $T: M_{3\times3}\to M_{3\times3}$ defined by $T(A) = 1/2(A+A^{\top})$. Determine a basis for the kernel of this mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

The linear transformation is given as $T: M_{3,3} \to M_{3,3}$ defined by $T(A) = 1/2(A+A^T)$. This is also known as the symmetrization operator.

Comment: No idea how to approach. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The question is asking the following: which matrices $A$ satisfy $T(A) = 0$?  The answer is that this only occurs for matrices that satisfy...?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a 3x3 zero matrix? Also, why would it be asking which matracies A satisfy T(A) = 0 when T(A) is given as 1/2(A+A^T)? Confused :(

Comment: What about $A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0}?$

Comment: To your second question, that's exactly what the "kernel of a transformation" is

Comment: Just saw that in the notes definition, my bad!

Comment: Quick follow up, would there then not be 3 matrices for each dimension a, b and c?

Comment: I don't know what your question means.  Yes, the kernel should be a $3$ dimensional subspace of $M_{3 \times 3}$.