# $T:\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2} \to \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$ such that $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t),~~ A\in \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$. Find $Im ~T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, transpose

> $T:\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2} \to \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$ such that $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t),~~ A\in \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$. show that T is linear, find $Ker~ T$, $Im ~T$

Attempt:

$T(A+B)=\frac{1}{2}(A+B+(A+B)^t)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t+B+B^t)=T(A)+T(B)$
Similarly $T(cA)=cT(A)$. So T is linear.

I can find $Ker~ T=\{A\in \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}/T(A)=O\}=\{A\in \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}/A=-A^t\}$ but unable to find $Im ~T$.

> How to find $Im ~T$?

Comment: Hint: Clearly $\text{Im}(T)$ is a subset if the symmetric matrices, is the converse true?

Comment: @Mathematician42 Please elaborate, I am unable to understand

Comment: My hint combined with the answer below should be sufficient to find the anwer yourself.

Comment: Some related older posts: [Linear transformation $T: M_{3\times3}\to M_{3\times3}$ defined by $T(A) = 1/2(A+A^{\top})$. Determine a basis for the kernel of this mapping.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1566079) and [Describe the image and kernel of a projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449724).

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{Ker}T$ is all Skew Symmetric Matrices..and $\operatorname{Im}T$ is all symmetric Matrices...Because every symmetric Matrix can be expressed as  $1/2(A+A')$ .

For any Symmetric Matrix $A = A'$ so any symmetric Matrix $A = 1/2(A+A')$. So every Symmetric Matrix of order $2$ has an preimage . So set of all symmetric Matrices of order two $S$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Im}T$.

Now we have to show $\operatorname{Im}T$ is a subset of $S$.
Now we will check whether there exists any $A$ for which $T(A)$ is not Symmetric. Every $T(A)$ is $1/2(A+A')$ which is a Symmetric Matric.
So Set of all Symmetric Matrices of order $2$ is $\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Comment: I know that $Im(T)=\{T(A)/A\in \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}\}=\{1/2(A+A')/A\in \mathbb{R}_{2\times 2} \}$. Please elaborate, how you have claimed?

Comment: Hiii@user1942348 This is the definition of $T(A)$ u made in ur qus...Btw sorry for late reply...I did not get notified...

Answer (score 0):

An idea (hint) for you to think about:

First, prove that **for any matrix** $\;A\in\Bbb R_{2\times2}\;$ , we have a decomposition:

$$A=\frac{A+A^t}2+\frac{A-A^t}2\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;\frac{A+A^t}2\;\;\text{symmetric and}\;\;\frac{A-A^t}2\;\;\text{antisymmetric}$$

or skew-symmetric .

Show now that the set $\;\mathcal A\;$ of symmetric matrices in $\;\Bbb R_{2\times2}\;$ is a subspace of dimension $\;3\;$, the set $\;\mathcal S\;$ of antisymmetric matrices is a subspace of dimension $\;1\;$, and

$$\text{Im}\,T=\mathcal A\;,\;\;\ker T=\mathcal S$$

Comment: I can show that $dim \;\mathcal A\;=3$ and  $dim \;\mathcal S\;=1$ considering standered basises in $\mathcal A\;$ and $\mathcal S\;$, respectvely. But how to conclude $\text{Im}\,T=\mathcal A\;,\;\;\ker T=\mathcal S$?

Comment: @user1942348 What about using the dimensions theorem, also known as the rank/nullity theorem ?

Comment: I can only say that rank/nullity thoerem hold good: $dim Ker{T}+\dim Im (T)=dim (\;\Bbb R_{2\times2}\;)$ if $3+1=4$, But how to conclude ImT=A,kerT=S

Comment: @user I think that you should really make a deeper effort: from the above it is trivial that  Im$\,T\subset\mathcal A\;$ ... **and they both have the same finite dimension** , thus ....